# CSS: How to add background-color with background-image under it (same color)

Tags: html, css

I want to add background-color to a div, and on the same div, on the bottom i want background-image. But when background-image begins, I want background-color to stop. Here is a image as example:

[image: CSS: How to add background-color with background-image under it (same color)]

Comment: Make two divs or use `:after`

Comment: [How to Create CSS3 Speech Bubbles Without Images](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with CSS, using 2 background images.

I made an illustration to be easier to understand:

[image: How to add background-color with background-image under it]

`background-image: url(http://www.yoursite.com/top_image.png), url(http://www.yoursite.com/bottom_image.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat;
background-position: left top, center top;`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using pure **CSS** - no image needed. Only **one** `div` is *required* to achieve this - **no need for two**!

You can apply whatever `background-color` you want without having to worry about it not being applied to the image.

Try changing the `background-color` in the demo!

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HN3ru/2/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow">BUTTON</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow {
    position: relative;
    background: #000000;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
}
.arrow:after {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested divs:

```
<div class="button">
    Text
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.button {
   background-color: black;
}

.arrow {
   background-image: ...
}
```

Of course you will have to adjust the positioning of the arrow image in the CSS, too.

Alternatively you could use `:after` to insert a pseudo element to represent the arrow.